# How do I write many cyclic voltammetry curves in Nova?

Tags: electrochemistry, software, cyclic-voltammetry

We are making an electrochemical research on supercapacitors that involves checking stability of our material. That requires repeated writing of cyclic voltammetry curves. Our goal is to write at least 2000 of them, but there is a problem with Nova software (version 1.8, to be specific): if we want to write even 50 cycles, Nova complains that "only last 30000 point will be written". We can adjust how many points are plotted, but when it comes to 2000 cycles, it's impossible to extract any information from them (15 points per one curve is just ludicrous).
Has anyone dealt with such problem? Is there a simple solution?

Comment: I would say that you should contact Autolab themselves. They must have a solution to this. Can't you take successive data files and overlay them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use command "repeat n-times", that will make n-data files and each can have 30 000 points. 
[image: powered by P. Mazur]